# Find and replace: \'

Tags: unix, sed

I'm trying to replace a every reference of `\'` with `&apos;` in a file

I've used variations of: `sed -e s/\'/"\&apos;"/g file.txt`

But they always replace every.single.(single).quote

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you want double quotes in the replacement, as in `"&apos;"`?

Comment: The Double quotes was my attempt at getting it to display &apos; verbatim (as a string instead of parsed as regex). I guess they're probably not needed.

Comment: Ah, okay. In your version, they won't show up, but if you single quote the whole command, they will.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure it's the best solution,I could do it like this:

```
sed "s/[\]'/\"\&apos;\"/g" file.txt
```

(putting the backslash character in a character range so it doesn't interfere with the following quote, and protect with double quotes)

Or just extending your syntax, without quotes but using almost the same trick:

```
sed -e s/[\\]\'/"\&apos;"/g file.txt
```

Comment: those single quotes are hell!

Comment: Yes - i'm a bit of a noob when it comes to command line as well :P Thanks again for your help!!

Answer (score 1):

An approach trying to conserve as much of the "single-quotedness" of the sed command as possible:

```
sed 's/\\'"'"'/\&apos;/g'
```

Just escaping `\` with `\\` and getting a single quote into the command with `'"'"'`: the first single quote ends the command so far, then we have a double-quoted single quote (`"'"`), and finally an opening single quote for the rest of the command.

Alternatively, double quoting the whole command and escaping both the backslash and single quote:

```
sed "s/\\\'/\&apos;/g"
```

Comment: Good to know, I had tried things like `\\\'` trying to get it to escape (figuring it would escape both the backslash and the single quote, but it didn't work. Thanks for your insight!

Comment: @Corey It actually works for me with `sed "s/\\\'/\&apos;/g"`, I'll add that.

Comment: Strange - I swear I tried that and it didn't work. Maybe my quotes were out of place. #sednoob

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax is:

```
$ echo "foo'bar" | sed 's/'\''/\&apos;/'
foo&apos;bar
```

Every script (sed, awk, whatever) should always be enclosed in single quotes and you just us other single quotes to stop/restart the script delimiters break out to shell for the minimal portion of the script that's absolutely necessary, in this case long enough to use `\'`. You need to break out to shell to specify that `'` because per shell rules no script enclosed in `'`s can contain a `'`, not even if you try to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo "foo'bar" | gawk '{gsub(/\47/,"\\&apos;")}1'

foo&apos;bar
```

The tricky part here is to replace a single quote with ampersand.
First in order to make the single quote manageable use its octal
code here \47 and then escaping ampersand by two back slash. And all of sudden
it becomes feasible :)

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!